# SharePoint 2007/2010 issues copying lists with hidden files using MetaVis

Tags: sharepoint, migrate

I'm working on migrating SharePoint lists (using MetaVis Migrator) and running into issues with files that seem to end in .000 files extension. Near as I can tell this was sometimes a temp file in SharePoint. (I'm not an SP expert)

Anyway, these files seem to be preventing me from migrating/copying lists using MetaVis. Anyone know if you can get rid of these or where they live?

Thanks,

Jes

Answer (score 0):

These extensions look more like items than documents. Try to copy them using item level copy that will let you to select content type in the destination list. You can contact support@metavistech.com so someone will guide you through the process.

Good luck with you migration,
Mark